# How to get the search box value and drop in href inside <span> tag

Tags: javascript, html, input, href, search-box

**Entering number in searchbox (*index.html*) and drop in href link**
 ***(search-pincode.html) inside `<span>` tag*** - I've got searchbox value when entering in *search-pincode.html* but when am trying from *index.html* page it doesn't work. no luck ! any help appreciated ! thanks in advance.

**HTML (index.html)**

```
<form class="form1" role="search" method="get" action="search-pincode.html">
<input class="pincode1" type="number" placeholder="Enter Postcode" id="user-pincode">
<button class="submit" type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Check</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
          <script>
              function myFunction() {
              var x = document.getElementById("user-pincode").value;
              document.getElementById("user-pincode-show").innerHTML = x;
              }
         </script>
```

**Output : search-pincode.html**

```
<h1 class="search-h1-contact">Yes, we install CCTV in <span id="user-pincode-show"></span></h1>
```

Comment: You are trying to get DOM of another page, how are you opening `search-pincode.html`?!

Comment: If User enter the number in searchbox and clicking on button its has to go `search-pincode.html` with that number

Comment: Please fix the error that you can see in console of your web browser. Add name attribute to `input#user-pincode`. After submitting the form you can get the value of parameter on the search-pincode.html page using some server side script, for example with PHP it will be GET[] array. For JS look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/979995/7663972) answer.